# Can't create JexlEngine object

Tags: java, jexl

I write the following class:

```
import org.apache.commons.jexl2.*;

public class NelderMead {
    // контсанты
    private static int      M = 3;
    private static double   E = 0.005;
    private static double   A = 1.000;
    private static double   B = 0.500;
    private static double   Y = 2.000;

    // переменные
    private JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine();
    private Expression func;
    private String funcString = "";
    private MapContext[] iterations;

    public NelderMead(){
        this.jexl = new JexlEngine();
    }

    public NelderMead(String funcString){
        this.jexl = new JexlEngine();
        this.setFunc(funcString);
    }


    public void setFunc(String funcString){
        this.funcString = funcString;
        this.func = this.jexl.createExpression(funcString);
    }

    public double funcEval(MapContext args){
        return (Double) this.func.evaluate(args);
    }

    public boolean checkCriterian(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

But the I create object of this class I have the foolowing error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlEngine$UberspectHolder.<clinit>(JexlEngine.java:121)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlEngine.getUberspect(JexlEngine.java:205)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlEngine.<init>(JexlEngine.java:182)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlEngine.<init>(JexlEngine.java:170)
    at NelderMead.<init>(NelderMead.java:22)
    at Test.main(Test.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 6 more
```

on first line of the constructor (when create an object of JexlEngine):

```
public NelderMead(String funcString){
    this.jexl = new JexlEngine();
    this.setFunc(funcString);
}
```

Could you help me - why this code cause the errors?

PS
I use .jar file to use this lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/download_logging.cgi) jar available in classpath at runtime

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error (Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.jexl3.MapContext) when I used the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Just add the following line to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-jexl3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And the project will be executed correctly.