# Error on Running Spring Java

Tags: java, spring

i am new on java spring, and want to learn it with a tutorial. On the tutorial i get following error: this error comes in another projects too... what is wrong?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.<init>(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:81)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.<init>(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:43)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractBeanFactory.java:176)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:159)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:170)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<init>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:165)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:78)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:67)
at org.semiz.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 9 more
```

here are the classes:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

public class DrawingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource(
                "spring.xml"));

        Triangle triangle = (Triangle) factory.getBean("triangle");
        triangle.draw();
    }
}

public class Triangle {

    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Triangle draw");
    }

}
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    
<beans>
  <bean id="triangle" class="org.semiz.Triangle"  />
   
 </beans>

Comment: refer to the solution of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278218/cant-create-jexlengine-object

Answer (score 3):

Looks like XmlBeanFactory has a logging dependency. You need to include [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi) jar in your classpath.